# Steam family share playing together

Tags: steam, steam-family-sharing

If my friend would share to my account and to HIS alt account at the same time and he plays from his alt where I play from my main account, can we play at the same time over a Steam account?

Answer (score 4):

No. Only one person can use a given shared library at a time.  If it's shared with multiple people, only one of them may use it at a time.

[See Steam Support:](https://help.steampowered.com/en/faqs/view/57A7-503C-991F-E9A8#simultaneous)

> **Can two users share a library and both play at the same time?**
>
> No, a shared library may only be played by one user at a time including
> the owner and ***even if they want to play different games***.

Comment: So, 2 people can't play 2 different games from the same library at the same time? Seems a bit underwhelming

Comment: @UnownK that is correct. Having multiple people sharing games that were bought once, doesn't seem so underwhelming to me :).

Comment: @Mixxiphoid One could do that with physical copies.

Comment: @UnownK Seems like that's exactly what it's trying to replicate, no?